# How to install universe on rpi

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi3, openai-gym

As the title states. I want to install universe on my raspberry pi 3. I want to code a learning gamebot

I have tried:

```
Pip install universe
```

But it returns errors.

Help pls

Comment: What error does it return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `numpy` and `golang` first and then install `universe` package.

**Run following command first:** (for ubuntu)

```
pip install numpy
sudo apt-get install golang libjpeg-turbo8-dev make
```

**and then run:**

```
pip install universe
```

**Ref:**

https://pypi.org/project/universe/

Comment: Package libjpeg-turbo8-dev is not available, but is referred to by anothrr package. 
This may mean that the package ui missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'libjpeg-turbo8-dev' has no installation candidate

Comment: @cephlot can you tell me which operating system ?

Comment: Raspbian the pre installed SD card